# fast way to get integers 0, 1, and 2 when given a random one from the set

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So basically

```
int num = rand(2); //random number from 0-2
int otherNum, otherOtherNum;
otherNum = implement this
otherOtherNum = implement this
```

For example, if num is 2, otherNum and otherOtherNum must be set to 0 and 1 (or 1 and 0).

How would you implement this? Assume you can't use branching or look up tables. Yes i'd like a bit manipulation solution. Yes i'd like the solution to be faster than a solution that uses modulus operator (as this is essentialy a division).

I think a lookup might be the fastest but not sure, I dont like that solution though.

Comment: This sounds like homework... can you clarify if it is so people can answer it in a guidance way rather than directly (the 2-x answer)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you want to just assign your three numbers to (0, 1, 2) randomly?

Comment: Must it be by bit manipulation? Can you use the modulo operator?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well, 2-x isn't the answer anyway..

Comment: I assume look-up tables implemented by in-register lookup are allowed? A 32-bit register can hold eight 4-bit entries, which seems more than enough. Table lookup is by shift and mask.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum not homework.

Comment: Look-up tables are explicitly forbidden. And how many entries do you think it would need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also do this with XOR and bit masking.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
f(unsigned val, unsigned ary[3])
{
    ary[0] = val;
    ary[1] = (ary[0] ^ 1) & 1;
    ary[2] = (ary[0] ^ 2) & 2;
}

int
main()
{
    unsigned ary[3] = {0};

    f(0, ary);
    printf("f(0) = %d %d %d\n", ary[0], ary[1], ary[2]);

    f(1, ary);
    printf("f(1) = %d %d %d\n", ary[0], ary[1], ary[2]);

    f(2, ary);
    printf("f(2) = %d %d %d\n", ary[0], ary[1], ary[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
f(0) = 0 1 2
f(1) = 1 0 2
f(2) = 2 1 0
```

Comment: This is super fast, how did you think of this? So unintuitive.

Answer (score 8):

```
otherNum = (num + 1) % 3
otherOtherNum = (num + 2) % 3
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use an in-register lookup table, if the restriction on look-up tables means avoiding memory access. The in-register lookup-table is simply a compile-time constant.

```
const int tab = ((1 <<  0) | (2 <<  4) | 
                 (0 <<  8) | (2 << 12) | 
                 (0 << 16) | (1 << 20));
int num = rand(2); //random number from 0-2
int otherNum, otherOtherNum;
otherNum = (tab >> num*8) & 0xf;
otherOtherNum = (tab >> (num*8+4)) & 0xf;
```

Comment: really neat idea, if shawley didn't tell me his solution which was slightly faster than yours i would have picked this one

Answer (score 3):

My 2 pee.

```
int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    int num = std::rand() % 3; //random number from 0-2

    int otherNum = (0b001001 >> (num << 1)) & 0b11;
    int otherOtherNum = (0b010010 >> (num << 1)) & 0b11;

    std::cout << num << '\n';
    std::cout << otherNum << '\n';
    std::cout << otherOtherNum << '\n';
}
```

**NOTES:**

```
0b001001 = 9
0b010010 = 18
0b11 = 3
```

This method basically uses a table stored in the bits of an integer and shifts the relevant bits into the desired variavle.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use an array for lookup, this avoids any additions and modulus although I'm not convinced it's faster at all:

```
int lookup[3] = {1, 2, 0};    
int num = rand(2); //random number from 0-2
int otherNum, otherOtherNum;
otherNum = lookup[num];
otherOtherNum = lookup[otherNum]
```